# Shutdown a TThreadPoolServer in python

Tags: python, thrift

I want to know how to shutdown a `TThreadPoolServer` properly.
Right now I use the following python code:

```
try:
    # Other settings
    transport = TSocket.TServerSocket(port=server_port)
    server = TServer.TThreadPoolServer(processor, transport, tfactory, pfactory)
    print("Starting server...")
    server.serve()
except (SystemExit, KeyboardInterrupt):
    transport.close()
    print("Done.!")
    exit(0)
```

After the server is started using terminal, I press `control-c`, "Done.!" is printed on the screen, but it doesn't exit and go back to command line. Can anybody help with this?
If I use `TSimpleServer`, it will terminated and go back to command line.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to [`.stop()`](http://people.apache.org/~thejas/thrift-0.9/javadoc/org/apache/thrift/server/TThreadPoolServer.html#stop%28%29) the `server`?